# Is $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \cup_{\partial \Delta^1 \times \Delta^1} \partial \Delta^1 \times I \to \Delta^1 \times I$ inner anodyne?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $I$ be the (nerve of the) walking isomorphism (a simplicial set). Consider the inclusion $\Delta^1 \to I$ and the inclusion $\partial \Delta^1 \to \Delta^1$. Take their [pushout-product](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pushout-product) to obtain a map

$$\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \cup_{\partial \Delta^1 \times \Delta^1} \partial \Delta^1 \times I \to \Delta^1 \times I$$

**Question 1:** Is this map a Joyal equivalence?

**Question 2:** Is this map (cellularly) inner anodyne?

If we reflect to $Cat$, then the map becomes an isomorphism. The content of this assertion is that if I have a commtutative square in a category $C$ and two opposite ends are isomorphisms, then we have an isomorphism in the arrow category $C^{\Delta^1}$.

I am fairly certain this is also true in quasicategories, so the answer to (1) is presumably *yes*. I'd like a direct proof of this fact, and the most straightforward proof would be to explicitly fill some horns and see that it's cellularly inner anodyne -- i.e. obtained just by gluing on some inner horns -- no retracts required, and no fancier Joyal trivial cofibrations required. But perhaps this is not possible.

Comment: It isn't difficult to prove that this map is inner anodyne, but I don't know whether it is cellularly so. I would think it rare for the most straightforward proof of a map's being inner anodyne to be to exhibit it explicitly as a cellular complex built out of inner horn inclusions (pushout products of inner horn inclusions with boundary inclusions being the only examples I can think of).

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Ah yes— every trivial cofibration into a quasicategory is inner anodyne right? What’s the most direct proof that this map is an equivalence then?

Comment: While it is true that every bijective-on-0-simplices trivial cofibration into a quasi-category is inner anodyne, it isn't necessary to use that fact to prove that this map is inner anodyne. I can type up a proof later, but if you want to give it a go yourself, begin from the observation that, since the codomain of this map is a quasi-category, it suffices to show that it has the LLP wrt all inner fibrations between quasi-categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is a proof that the map in question is inner anodyne that does not proceed by explicitly filling inner horns.

By definition (more or less), a map is inner anodyne iff it has the LLP wrt all inner fibrations; but if moreover the codomain of that map is a quasi-category, as in our example, it suffices by pull-back to show that it has the LLP wrt all inner fibrations between quasi-categories.

So let $p \colon X\to Y$ be an inner fibration between quasi-categories. By adjointness, the pushout-product of the boundary inclusion $i \colon \partial\Delta^1 \to \Delta^1$ with the inclusion $j \colon \Delta^1 \to \mathbb{I}$ has the LLP wrt $p$ iff the inclusion $j$ has the LLP wrt to the "pullback-internal hom" of $i$ and $p$, $\{i.p\} \colon \operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^1,X) \to \operatorname{Fun}(\partial\Delta^1,X) \times_{\operatorname{Fun}(\partial\Delta^1,Y)}\operatorname{Fun}(\Delta^1,Y)$.

Now, since $i$ is a bijective-on-0-simplices monomorphism and $p$ is an inner fibration between quasi-categories, this map $\{i,p\}$ is a conservative inner fibration between quasi-categories.

So the result follows from the fact that any conservative inner fibration between quasi-categories has the RLP wrt to the inclusion $j \colon \Delta^1 \to \mathbb{I}$. This is a consequence of Joyal's special outer horn lifiting theorem, for this inclusion $j \colon \Delta^1 \to \mathbb{I}$ can be built up by filling outer horns $\Lambda^n_n \to \Delta^n$ for $n > 1$ all of whose final edges are the edge of the original domain $\Delta^1$.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Where can I find Joyal’s special outer horn lifting theorem? I suppose this reduces the question to showing that $\Delta^1 \to I$ is right anodyne. For this part is an explicit horn filling argument easier than the direct one I gave? Or is the idea instead to use Quillen’s theorem A?

Comment: It’s in Joyal’s original paper on quasi-categories and Kan complexes from 2002. The explicit horn filling of $\Delta^1 \to I$ is much easier, as there’s just one horn to be filled in each dimension; I think I remember seeing it in one of the Riehl-Verity papers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is *yes*, the map $P = \partial \Delta^1 \times I \cup_{\partial \Delta^1 \times \Delta^1} \Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \to \Delta^1 \times I$ is cellularly inner anodyne. Here is a proof. I'd still be curious to see a proof that this map is an equivalence which doesn't use explicit horn-filling.

An $n$-simplex of $\Delta^1$ corresponds to a cut in $[n] = \{0,\dots,n\}$. Labeling the cut by the first point after it, we get a bijection between $(\Delta^1)_n$ and $\{0,\dots,n+1\}$.

Call the objects of $I$ $\{-,+\}$, where $\Delta^1$ is included mapping from $-$ to $+$. Since $I$ is codiscrete, we can name the $n$-simplices of $I$ by the objects they traverse, getting a bijection between $I_n$ and $\{-,+\}^{n+1}$.

Thus $(\Delta^1 \times I)_n \cong \{0,\dots,n+1\} \times \{-,+\}^{n+1}$. Face maps may be computed by deleting coordinates. If the first coordinate is $0$ or $n+1$, then the simplex is already in $\partial \Delta^1 \times I$, so we need only consider those simplices $(i,x) \in \{1,\dots, n\} \times \{-,+\}^{n+1}$. Such a simplex is degenerate unless the string $x$ alternates between $-$ and $+$ at every place, with the possible exception that we might have $x_i = x_{i-1}$.

Thus there are $4n$ nondegenerate $n$-simplices in $\Delta^1 \times I \setminus \partial \Delta^1 \times I$. We label them by a tuple $(i,\delta, x_0)_n \in \{1,\dots, n\} \times \{-,+\}^2$, where $i$ gives the coordinate in $\Delta^1$, $x_0$ is the first entry of the list $x$ in the representation of the previous paragraph, and $\delta = x_{i-1} x_i$ is $+$ if $x_i = x_{i-1}$ and $-$ if $x_i = -x_{i-1}$.

Let us use inner horn fillings to construct $\Delta^1 \times I$ from $P = \partial \Delta^1 \times I \cup_{\partial \Delta^1 \times \Delta^1} \Delta^1 \times \Delta^1$. Recall that filling a horn $\Lambda^n_i \to \Delta^n$ in a simplicial set $X$ adds two new nondegenerate simplices -- the "filler" of dimension $n$, and the "composite" of dimension $n-1$, which is the $i$th face of the filler. The other faces of the filler must already be present in $X$, and if we are trying to build up a specific $Y \supset X$, then it's important that the filler and the composite both *not* be already present in $X$ before the filling.

**$0$-simplices:** These are all already present in $P$.

**$1$-simplices:** We already have $(1,+,+)_1,(1+,-)_1,(1,-,+)_1 \in \Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \subset P$, and we just need to add $(1,-,-)_1$. We add this as a $\Lambda^2_1$ composite with filler $(1,+,-)_2$ (we could alternatively have used filler $(2,+,-)_2$).

From here on, the $n$th stage of filling will have $2n-1$ nondegenerate $n$-simplices in $\Delta^1 \times I \setminus P$ already present. The remaining $2n+1$ nondegenerate $n$-simplices in $\Delta^1 \times I \setminus P$ are added as composites. The filler-composite pairs will be assigned as follows:

- For $i = 1$ and $x_0 = \pm 1$, we make $(1,+,x_0)_{n+1}$ a filler via $\Lambda^{n+1}_1$ with composite $(1,-,x_0)$.
- For $i = 2,\dots, n$ and $\delta x_0 = (-1)^i$, the simplex $(i,\delta,x_0)_{n+1}$ will be a filler via $\Lambda^{n+1}_i$ with composite $(i,-\delta,x_0)$.
- For $i = n$, we additionally make $(n+1,+,(-1)^{n+1})_{n+1}$ a filler via $\Lambda^{n+1}_n$ with composite $(n, -, (-1)^{n+1})_n$.

**$2$-simplices:** We already have $(1,+,+)_2, (2,+,+)_2 \in \Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \subset P$, and we just added $(1,+,-)_2$ as a filler. The remaining 5 simplices are added as composites as above.

**$3$-simplices and higher:** There are no more nondegenerate simplices in $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^1 \subset P$. We have $2n-1$ $n$-simplices which were added as fillers at the previous stage, and the remaining $2n+1$ are added as composites at this stage.

**Proof of correctness:**
It turns out that at the $n$th stage, most of the above horns can be glued on directly to what we already have from the previous stage, with 3 exceptions (or rather, 2 exceptions when $n = 2$). The exceptional gluings are composite / filler pairs $(2,-,x_0)_n / (2,+,x_0)_{n+1}$ for $x_0 = \pm 1$, and the composite / filler pair $(n,1,x_0)_n / (n,-1,x_0)_{n+1}$ for $x_0 = (-1)^n$. The first two depend on having previously glued in in the composite / filler pair $(1,-,+)_n / (1,+,+)_{n+1}$, while the last one depends on having previously glued in the composite / filler pair $(n,-,(-1)^{n+1})_n / (n+1,+,(-1)^{n+1})_{n+1}$.

These assertions can be verified using the following calculuations, for $n \geq 2$:

**For $i = 2,\dots, n$:** We have $$\partial_0(i,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} = (i-1,\delta,-x_0)_n$$
$$\partial_{i-1}(i,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} = (i-1,-\delta,x_0)_n$$
$$\partial_i(i,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} = (i,-\delta,x_0)_n$$
$$\partial_{n+1}(i,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} = (i,\delta,x_0)_n$$

and all other faces are degenerate.

**For $i = 1$:** We have
$$\partial_0(1,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} \in \partial \Delta^1 \times I$$
$$\partial_1(1,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} = (1,-\delta,x_0)_n$$
$$\partial_{n+1}(1,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} = (1,\delta,x_0)_n$$

and all other faces are degenerate.

**For $i = n+1$:** We have
$$\partial_0(n+1,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} = (n,\delta,-x_0)_n$$
$$\partial_n(n+1,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} = (n,-\delta,x_0)_n$$
$$\partial_0(n+1,\delta,x_0)_{n+1} \in \partial \Delta^1 \times I$$

and all other faces are degenerate.

**Note:** It seems most of the above procedure is forced -- by my count, at each stage there was only one choice to make about which filler to use to get a certain composite.